# Terras lemma proof

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

For any number N the parity vector v(N) is defined as $v_i(N) = S_i \pmod 2$

If N is a positive integer of the form $a\cdot 2^k + b (b < 2^k)$
then the first k elements of the parity vector are dependent on b only

The proof is by induction on k.
For k = 1 we have $N = 2\cdot a + b$ with b either 0 or 1
and the lemma is true by the definition of the 3x + 1 algorithm
Now assume the lemma is true for some k
Let $N = a\cdot 2^{k+1} + b (b < 2^{k+1})$
Then if $S_0 = N$ is even $S_1 = a\cdot 2^k + b / 2$
and if $S_0 = N$ is odd $S_1 = 3\cdot a\cdot 2^k + (3b+1) / 2$
In either case the first k elements of v(S1) depend on b only
Therefore the first k+1 elements of N are independent of a as well
This concludes the proof of the lemma.

I am trying to understand the proof.
Is the inductive hypotesis used when it is said that the first k elements of $v(s_1)$ depend only on b?

Is correct that the First k elements of v(S1) depend on b only because in every case $a\cdot 2^k$ is even for k steps and so the party Vector depends only on b?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $S_i$ is a "Collatz sequence" given by $S_0=N$ and $S_{i+1}=\begin{cases} \frac12S_i & S_i\text{ even}\\ \frac12(3S_i+1)& S_i\text{ odd}.\end{cases}$

Yes, that is where the inductive hypothesis is used.